# Facebook new API permissions request denied

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

After the new update to how facebook api needs to get their permissions reviewed by the team I've ran into an problem.

**Background:** We have developed a facebook theme for wordpress that functions similar to kickstarter, but instead of pledging cash users pledge shares on social networks. We need every theme owner to be able to manage their own facebook application (branding, settings and everything).

**Problems with requested permissions:**

**publish_actions** When I submitted the app for review, my publish actions were denied. (the theme doesn't post unless the goal is met and the project expires and I don't know how to explain that to facebook dev-team). 
Reason we got denied:

> *We could not reproduce the requested permission. Please submit detailed, step-by-step instructions in the "Add Notes" section of the permission, and make sure to provide the relevant version of your app. See here for additional information on login permission requirements.*

(we have provided that tho)

**read_friendlists** We need to be able to see the friendlist of the user, for friend number, and to make sure we don't count the same user twice for the same campaign.

> You have requested excessive permissions. Please ensure the requested information is not already available in the public_profile field.

user_friends just doesn't cut it, since we cannot expect peoples friends to all use that app

How should I address that, and how to get my theme buyers through submit and approval process? Is there any way to get my app users pre-approved or something ?

Comment: I think you should look at the documentation for /user/friendlists https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friendlists . It only returns the name of the friendlists not the friends. Getting all friends is not possible in API v2.0

Comment: Isn't there any way we could at least get the number of facebook contacts a user has ?

Comment: What do you need number of friends for? And for publish_actions what are you publishing?

Comment: Number of friends = users social reach (so we know if social reach goal is reached). And we publish the link the campaign starter set with message the user submitted. (in some finished campaigns about blood-drives and environment awareness)

Comment: _“users pledge shares on social networks”_ – what does that actually mean …? If users are rewarded for this in any way, then that’s a violation of Platform Policies right there already. And if you are planning on posting those links for a large number of users simultaneously (or within a very short time frame) after the goal of the “campaign” is reached, I think Facebook’s algorithms might not look at that to kindly either – even if they don’t consider it spam right away, _reduced_ newsfeed distribution/visibility is something you should expect.

Comment: The whole concept sounds kinda fishy to me … I think you’d be much better of with letting users share what they feel like sharing _when_ they feel like sharing it – instead of trying to focus this on one specific “campaign goal reached” moment.

Comment: Our theme is based on this website -> https://www.thunderclap.it/en . It offers same functionality. And besides feeling warm and fuzzy inside for helping someone get a word out, people aren't incentivized. And there's throttling added to api calls, so we don't spike it needlessly. I think we're just fine with the website as it is, i was just wondering about the approval process.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has likely denied the `publish_actions` permission, as the user should be explicitly sharing something to their wall. Facebook doesn't like automatic / background sharing, unless the user has given content. Make sure your application has a checkbox the user can select / unselect allowing them to opt-out of sharing.

You should be requesting the `user_friends` permission, instead of the `read_friendslists` permission. This will allow you to see the user's friends, but it will be limited to the friends who are already using the application. You won't be able to retrieve friend count using this endpoint.